# Scrapy css selector get text from occurence of first class

Tags: python, css, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape text from class .s-recipe-header__info-item, but as you can see on the picture, there are three classes with the same name and I would like to extract only the first one to get text "Do hodiny" [See the image of code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOzpP.png). So far I have tried this code:

recipe_item["preparation_time"] = response.css(".s-recipe-header__info > .s-recipe-header__info-items > .s-recipe-header__info-item::text").extract_first()

I have also tried to use .get() instead of .extract_first(), but both do not seem to work...

I am new to web scraping and I have only elemental HTML and CSS knowledge. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: It would be much easier to help you if you provided the link.

Comment: Of course, here is the link to the website: https://www.apetitonline.cz/recept/francouzske-brambory-se-syrem